# Optimization of render datatables

Tags: javascript, php, performance, datatables, rendering

I'm using jQuery datatables and client-side rendering.

With the code below I'm trying to replace `{{number}}` by array elements and it does work as expected.

In PHP I have:

```
<?php
$returnTmp2['test'] = array(100,'/Home/','Home');
return $returnTmp2;
?>
```

I'm trying to replace the dynamic values by the mRender-function of Datatables:

```
$datatableContent['render'] = '<a href="{{1}}{{0}}/">{{2}}</a>';
```

I'd like to have this output:

```
<a href="/Home/100/">Home</a>
```

The trouble is the huge load time when I've got plenty of rows (more than 20 secs).
Do you know any method to optimalise the code in the picture below?

[image]

***Update***

Complete code visible at: http://pastebin.com/RHTv0S5N

Comment: Which version of dt are u using? How many rows are 'plenty'?

Comment: I'm using v1.9.1 of jQuery Datatables and with plenty I mean at least 12.175 rows (it's used in a CMS f.e. for the orders and newsletter subscriptions module)

Comment: That is a lot, indeed ;-) But Pagnination should help there, I guess you rarely need to see all records at once...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good, but involves a bit of processing, so I'd recommend to make it easier for the client (assuming you always have an array with {number, url,name} then I'd do

`"mRender": function (data, type full)
{
   return '<a href=\'' + data[1] + data[0] + '\'>' + data[2] + '</a>';
}`

Enabling pagination will also help to accelerate rendering...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm afraid there isn't just one single render output. Some fields are just strings (PHP prevents them being rendered by "mRender"), but the other fields expect an array with an undefined number of items.

Some examples:
`array('greyOrder','Paid')` => `<span class="{{0}}">{{1}}</span>`, `array('/Orders/1/','Demo Customer','D. Customer')` => `<a href="{{0}}" title="{{1}}">{{2}}</a>`

Comment: You don't have to use a single mRender for the entire table, you can use aoColumnDefs (http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html ) to provide specific rendering for individual columns ...

Comment: I'm indeed using "mRender" inside "aoColumnDefs", but I'm using one single PHP-code in combination with a settings array to show all datatables. In this way I don't have "/js/datatables.orders.js", "/js/datatables.files.js", "/js/datatables.images.js", but one file "/js/datatable.php" which will be included.

Comment: All in all, I think there will not much to be gained anyway with that change - the most effective gains I had with such large tables was...by not showing everything immediately, i.e. by providing a search beforehand, so to reduce the # of records and/or by using pagination...
(There's also a small improvement to be gained by setting `bAutoWidth: false` and setting column-widths with CSS, but again, it won't help much, I guess... Such a lot of rows just need time...)